# Not understanding Formatting of number in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a routine that returns an integer and I am trying to format it to display it in a label.

Dim Freq as Integer = 14145240

Label3.text=String.Format("{0:##,##0.000}", Freq)

In the label I want it to be displayed like 14,145.240

I understand about the decimal and thousands separator and I have tried using "N3" with the culture variant but alway no matter what I try its not coming out correct. if I use Freq.ToString it shows the label as 14145240 if I just use Freq it shows as 14,145,240.
The first digits maybe 1 or 2 digits in length so it could be 14 or just 6 but I still want the layout to look the same.
Thanks

Comment: please read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Comment: `14145240` is a whole integer number. You can not display is as a decimal number without converting it to decimal. To me it looks like you should divide this number by 1000 and store the result in decimal variable and then display that decimal variable in a label..

Comment: That is an integer, of course its representation would not have a decimal separator.

Comment: I don't know why I did not think of that.. I appreciate the answers!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should divide the number by 1000 for getting the desired format:

`Label3.text=String.Format("{0:##,##0.000}", Freq/1000.0)`